# Checkbox mysql php

Tags: php

```
    <form action="execute_new.php" id="modalform" method="post">
                          <td width="147"> <strong>
                           <font color="#033">Sticker No:</font><font color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
                          <td width="146"><input type="text" name="stickerno" /></td>
                          <tr>
                          <td><strong>
                           <font color="#033">TO : </font></td>
                           </tr>
                          <tr>
                          <td >
                          <input name="fname" type="text"  />
                          </td>
                          <td >
                          <input name="mname" type="text"  />
                          </td>
                          <td width="143" align="right">
                          <input name="lname" type="text"  /> 
                          </td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                          <td>
                          First Name</font><font color="#FF0000">*</font>
                          </td>
                          <td >
                         Middle Name</font><font color="#FF0000">*</font>
                          </td>
                        <td>
                          Last Name</font><font color="#FF0000">*</font>
                          </td>
                          </tr>


          </table><br>
<br>

<table>
                        <tr>
                          <td><strong>
                           <font color="#033"> ADDRESS:</font></font><font color="#FF0000">*</font> </td>
                          <td align="center"><input name="address" type="text" value="" size="70"></td>

</tr>
          </table>
                      <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <font color="#033">
                 <table border="15" bgcolor="#00FF66" bordercolor="#000000"  width="650" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">

                 <br>
                 <br>
    <tr>
        <td >LICENSE NO:<font color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="license"/></td>
        <td >BIRTH DATE:</td>

        <td align="center"><input name="bdate" id="demo1" type="text"><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo1','ddmmmyyyy',true,12)"><img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a></td>

    <tr>
        <td >PLATE NO:<font color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="plateno"/></td>
        <td >PUV BODY NAME:</td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="puvbname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >TYPE OF VEHICLE:</td>
        <td align="center"><select id="vehicletype" name="vehicletype" style="width:134px">                      
<option value="Private">Private</option>
<option value="Public">Public</option>
</select>
        <td >PUV BODY NO:</td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="puvbno" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >OWNER OF VEHICLE:</td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="vehicleowner" /></td>
        <td >ADDRESS:</td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="taddress" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >PLACE OF VIOLATION:<font color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="violationplace" /></td>
        <td>DATE / TIME:<font color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
        <td align="center"><input name="datetime" id="demo2" type="text"><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo2','ddmmmyyyy',true,12)"><img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a>

    </tr>

        </table><br>
       <table border="15" bordercolor="#000000"  width="150" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                     <tr>Confiscated:</tr>
                     <br>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="License ID" id="RadioGroup1_0" checked>License ID</tr><br>
          <tr><td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="License O.R." id="RadioGroup1_1">License O.R.</tr>

                        <tr>
<td>                          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="TCP/TOP" id="RadioGroup1_2">
                          TCP/TOP</tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="License Plate" id="RadioGroup1_3">
                          License Plate</tr>
                          <tr><td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Not Confiscated" id="RadioGroup1_4">
                          Not Confiscated</tr>
                      </tr></table><br />
                              <center><strong>You are hereby cited for committing the traffic violations / checked hereunder</strong><br /></center>

<br>
<br>               <table width="100%px" border="7" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" bordercolordark="#000000" style="font-size:13px">
   <tr>                  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Unattended/Illegaly Parked Vehicle" /> 
Unattended / Illegaly Parked Vehicle</td> 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Out of Line Operation/Route Violation" />
Out of Line Operation/Route Violation</br></td>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Illegal Parking" />
Illegal Parking</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Trip Cutting" />
  Trip Cutting</br></td>
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Illegal Topload" />
Illegal Topload</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Over Charging" />
Over Charging</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Truck Ban/Tricycle Ban" /> 
Truck Ban/Tricycle Ban</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Refusal to Convey Passenger"/>
  Refusal to Convey Passenger</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Driving in Slippers/Sleeveless shirt" /> 
Driving in Slippers/Sleeveless shirt</td> 
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Overspeeding/Drag Racing/Reckless Driving" />Overspeeding/Drag Racing/Reckless Driving</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Driving w/o License/Expired/Invalid License" /> 
Driving w/o License/Expired/Invalid License</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="One-way Street Violation" />One-way Street Violation</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="No PUV ID" /> 
No PUV ID</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Illegal Loading/Unloading" />Illegal Loading/Unloading</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Driving Dilapidated">
Driving Dilapidated</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Traffic Obstruction"/>Traffic Obstruction</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Junk Vehicle" /> 
Junk Vehicle</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Disregarding Traffic Sign/Light" />Disregarding Traffic Sign/Light</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="No Smoking 20% Discount Sticker" />
No "No Smoking"/20% Discount Sticker</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Illegal Blowing of Horn"  />Illegal Blowing of Horn</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="No Permit Decalsticker"  /> 
No Permit Decalsticker</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Failure to obey Police Order"  />Failure to obey Police Order</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Stereo Set Operated at Excessive Sound Volume" />
Stereo Set Operated at Excessive Sound Volume</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="No Helmet/Head Gear"  />
  No Helmet/Head Gear</td>
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="No Trash Can/Receptacle" />
No Trash Can/Receptacle</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Smoke Belching" />
  Smoke Belching</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Colorum PUV" />
Colorum PUV</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Failure to Switch Headlights" />Failure to Switch Headlights</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="No Plate"  /> 
No Plate</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="No U-turn" /> No U-turn</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Driving under the Influence of Liquor" /> 
Driving under the Influence of Liquor</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Dirty Plate" />
 Dirty Plate</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Counter Flow" />
Counter Flow</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Arrogant Driver/Conductor" />Arrogant Driver/Conductor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Driver's/Conductor's Uniform/I.D." /> 
Driver's/Conductor's Uniform / I.D.</td>
<td><input type="text" name="oviolation" />
  Other Traffic Violations(Specify)</td>
</tr></table>

<br>
                        </label>
                      <p align="center">
                      <p align="center"><strong>Apprehending Office ( Rank &amp; Name )</strong><font color="#FF0000">*</font></p>
                        <label>                        </label>
                         <select name="type" size="1">
          <option>Job Order</option>
          <option>Permanent</option>
        </select>
                        <input type="text" name="officer" placeholder="Officer Name"/> 
                      </p>

                      <h5 align="center">PUBLIC ORDER &amp; SAFETY OFFICE</h5>
                      <h5 align="center">&nbsp;</h5>
                      <h5 align="center">
                      </h5>

          </font>
      <input type="submit" name="register" value="Add" class="adds"/>
                        <input type="reset" name="cancel"  value="Reset" class="add"/>
                        <br />
                      </h5>


                    </form>
 <?php

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("dbposo",$conn);


    if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {
        $license=$_POST['license'];


        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblviolator WHERE license = '$license'");
        $fetch_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ( $fetch_rows > 0 )
    {
        echo "<script>alert('License # already exist')</script>";
            header("Refresh: 0;url=new.php");
    }

    elseif( empty($_POST['stickerno']))
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Please check if all the * marker field is filled!')</script>";
            header("Refresh: 0;url=new.php");
        }

    else
        {
        $stickerno=$_POST['stickerno'];
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $mname=$_POST['mname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];
        $bdate=$_POST['bdate'];
        $plateno=$_POST['plateno'];
        $puvbname=$_POST['puvbname'];
        $vehicletype=$_POST['vehicletype'];
        $puvbno=$_POST['puvbno'];
        $vehicleowner=$_POST['vehicleowner'];
        $taddress=$_POST['taddress'];
        $violationplace=$_POST['violationplace'];
        $datetime=$_POST['datetime'];
        $confiscated=$_POST['RadioGroup1'];
        $violation=$_POST['cbox'];
        $oviolation=$_POST['oviolation'];
        $type=$_POST['type'];
        $officer=$_POST['officer'];

            mysql_query("insert into tblviolator(license, stickerno, fname, mname, lname, address, bdate, plateno, puvbname, vehicletype, puvbno, vehicleowner, taddress, violationplace, datetime, confiscated, violation, oviolation, type, officer) values('$license','$stickerno','$fname','$mname','$lname','$address','$bdate','$plateno','$puvbname','$vehicletype','$puvbno','$vehicleowner','$taddress','$violationplace','$datetime','$confiscated','$violation','$oviolation','$type','$officer')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());

            echo "<script>alert('Successfully Recorded, <br>
            First penalty: 100php!')</script>";
            header("Refresh: 0;url=new.php");
        }

    }

    ?>
```

What is my error here?

Comment: Also post you html content

Comment: @krishna your comment is not correct check it first

Comment: @krishna its now editted. the html content is there

Comment: change `$violation=$_POST['cbox'];` to `$violation=implode(',' $_POST['cbox'])` because $violation will be array if you select more than one option

Comment: i try that and this appear 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\THESIS\execute_new.php on line 45

Comment: try my answer which has better checks

Comment: @krishna that is your answers error

Comment: sorry i just missed out `,` in my `implode()`. just check it now.

Comment: @krishna what should i do now? :(

Comment: try this 
  `if(is_array($_POST['cbox']))
    $violation=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']);
    else
    $violation=$_POST['cbox']; `

Comment: do you have facebook mam? :( i can't get what you want me to do :/ im beginner :( please help :'(

Comment: in your old code please change this `$violation=$_POST['cbox'];` to `if(is_array($_POST['cbox'])) $violation=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']); else $violation=$_POST['cbox'];`

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 <-- error :(

Comment: do you use the same query used here ?

Comment: yes mam i just copy it

Comment: $confiscated=$_POST['RadioGroup1'];
 if(is_array($_POST['cbox'])) $violation=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']); else $violation=$_POST['cbox'];
 $oviolation=$_POST['oviolation'];

Comment: '$confiscated=$_POST['RadioGroup1'];
 if(is_array($_POST['cbox'])) $violation=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']); else $violation=$_POST['cbox'];
 $oviolation=$_POST['oviolation'];'

Comment: i just change my $violation=$_POST['cbox']; to if(is_array($_POST['cbox'])) $violation=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']); else $violation=$_POST['cbox']; like what you said mam

Comment: first of all i am a boy so please stop saying me as Mam and you could call me as krishna

Comment: i tried your code which works fine for me in inserting

Comment: oops im sorry @krishna, why is this --> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 :(

Comment: the error is saying you have problem in insert query. So are you using the same query you posted here or any different insert query ?. because when i tried to use your code i got values inserted.

Comment: its working now sir :) but why is that no appearing of message box? sorry for my bad english

Comment: because you are redirecting a page and anything you display before `header()` will not be displayed

Comment: what is the best way to stay on page after submitting but erase all the values of fields?

Comment: you have to use jquery or unset all post varaibles of that form

Comment: thank you very much sir. im realy honored that you teach me :) im very very thankful :)

Comment: i can't vote because my reputation is too low xD I'll just remember this thread and I'll vote for you :)

Comment: i have new thread sir please help me :) thank you in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879917/warning-mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-table-cant-fetc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you select more than one checkbox then $_POST['cbox'] becomes array .so try this

```
if(is_array($_POST['cbox']))
$violation=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']);
else
$violation=$_POST['cbox'];
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid injection better use http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

If you check more than one option for the checkbox the variable $violation will be an array. Try to check multiple options and just safe the first one. 
Probably if you want to store it as varchar you shoud concatenate all values.

Comment: if i check many it will become array.

and if i save it the message box will not appear, but it save to the database

Comment: And whats the value of column violation? Check multiple options and use on the query '$violation[0]'.Check if it works.

Comment: violation is the checkbox. i try that one, but it select index 0 of my checkbox, it save the first array to the database

Comment: Thats ok, is the expected behavior. Then if you check more than one option you shoud save all position of the array $violation. To do this you can concatenate all values in one string and use this string to the query.

Comment: but what i want to do is, i want multiple checkbox and save it to the database how was it?

Comment: One options is that way, the other possible way is having many columns as values for the checkboxes. Ex: 3 possible values for checkbox, 3 columns.
For the first option use @krishna code.